# How can I split a string on the first occurrence of something?

Tags: php

I know "explode" splits the string and turns it into an array for every occurrence. But how do I split on the first occurrence and keep everything after the first occurrence?

**Examples:**

```
$split = explode('-', 'orange-yellow-red');
echo $split[1]; // output: "yellow"
```

^ I would like this to output: **yellow-red**

```
$split = explode('-', 'chocolate-vanilla-blueberry-red');
echo $split[1]; // output: "vanilla"
```

^ I would like this to output: **vanilla-blueberry-red**

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can pass the `limit` as the third parameter of [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) that will do the job.

```
$split = explode('-', 'orange-yellow-red',2);
echo $split[1]; //output yellow-red
```

Answer (score 12):

Have a look at the third parameter of `explode`:

> `$limit`
>
> If limit is set and positive, the returned array will contain a maximum of limit elements with the last element containing the rest of string.
>
> If the limit parameter is negative, all components except the last -limit are returned.
>
> If the limit parameter is zero, then this is treated as 1.

```
$a=explode('-','chocolate-vanilla-blueberry-red', 2);
echo $a[1]; // outputs vanilla-blueberry-red
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$split = explode('-', 'chocolate-vanilla-blueberry-red');
unset($split[0]);
echo implode('-', $split); # vanilla-blueberry-red
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution without a variable :

```
strtok('orange-yellow-red', '-');
echo strtok(null);
```

Comment: Interesting solution, works :)
But per definition, first parameter of strtok has to be of type "string", "null" isn't allowed.

Answer (score 0):

a regular expression perhaps?

```
[^-]+-
```

Comment: regex is way more expensive than a simple `explode('sep', 'foobar', 2);`